# Item added to DbContext twice

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I am very new to SP.NET MVC, so excuse me for missing basic stuff.

I have created a website working with a database (Microsoft SQL Server) and I'm using Entity Framework package to manage it.

I have a DatabaseManager class as following:

```
Public class DatabaseManager : DbContext 
{
    Public DbSet<Connection> Connections { get; set; }
.
.
.
}
```

My application listens for syslog connections and then updates the Connections member accordingly:

```
Db.connections.Add(new Connection(SourceIp, DestinationIp))
db.SaveChanges();
```

Anyway, however weird it may seem, when I add a connection to the DbContext two connection are added (both identical) instead of one.

What might be my problem?

Comment: Did you debug and see at what point the second one is getting added?

Comment: I have been trying to debug yet not much luck. In the function where I add the entry to the connection it looks like there is only one entry in db.Connections yet in the Index function in my controller the db.connections has two items.

Comment: Maybe you are calling the function twice? Remember that if you are debugging the code and hold the code execution for more than two or three seconds the browsers have the "bad" habit of reissuing the request...

Comment: Turns out that it was all my fault - I just created the listener thread more than once therefore causing packets to be added multiple times to the database. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have registered event listener twice or included the registering file (may be JS file) twice, this issue would come. You can any time check at Firebug with list of events attached..